# Is there a term for the element of a relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

If a relation is a subset of the Cartesian product of two sets, is there a special term for an individual element of a relation? Might that term be "relationship"?

Comment: I'd just call it an "element". If you've set things up so that everything is a set, there's no need to invent new words for set-like operations!

Comment: Agreed. Each element of a relation is simply an ordered pair of elements of the underlying set.

Answer (score 2):

You might, I suppose, say that the pair $\langle 1, 2\rangle$ is an *instance* of the 'less than' relation, if you want to say close to informal talk about relations.

(Mind you, call me pernickety, but I'd rather you didn't say the relation is a set of ordered pairs -- the set is the *extension* of the relation. But that's a sermon for another occasion!)

Comment: I'm curious about this extension. Do you have a reference to something simple?

Comment: "Pernickety" is ironic. 

Comment: What goes here in my remarks about functions https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479936/in-what-manner-are-functions-sets goes for relations too.